# How to Handle the java,net.SocketException error in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running the load test with 100 users in JMeter.

Application is working fine, but when I increase the load up to 200 users, few of the transactions getting failed.

The error is Non HTTP Response code:

```
java.net.SocketException
```

Answer (score 1):

The error can have many causes.
Some steps you may take to diagnoses are:

- Use latest version of JMeter
- Enable DEBUG mode in JMeter
- Set Connection timeout
- Delay Thread Creation
- Disable Parallel Downloads
- Configure trusted and client SSL certs
- Tweak JMeter SSL configuration
- Enable stale connection check
- Enable HTTP Keep-Alive on web servers
- Check the load balancer configuration

More details [on this article](https://www.xtivia.com/fixing-jmeter-socket-errors/).